# Are these database tables normalized?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization

I am developing a webapp for an institute and I designed these tables:

[image]

Are these tables normalized?

Comment: what is DefineClass? Does it just link the student to the class?

Comment: Can more than one teacher teach a class together? Explain how Course and Class are different--and whether a course occurs only once or multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Are they normalised?

No.

Student has Mob1 and Mob2 fields.